# Symfony Bundle not creating bundle-configuration yaml file in project

Tags: symfony, bundle, symfony-bundle

A so far working bundle now needs its own configuration file inside the projects using the bundle, to manage bundle settings individually.

However, no matter which approach I use (the old one before Symfony 6.1 nor the new one  extending `AbstractBundle`) there is - at no time - any new `.yaml`-File created inside the projects `./config/packages/` directory.

---

This is my code (the old style, prior to Symfony 6.1, extending `Bundle`):

#### Bundle Class

*mycorpforms/src/MyCorpFormsBundle.php*

```php
<?php

namespace MyCorp\FormsBundle;

use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Configurator\DefinitionConfigurator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\ExtensionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\Configurator\ContainerConfigurator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class MyCorpFormsBundle extends Bundle
{
   // empty
}
```

#### Configuration

*mycorpforms/src/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php*

```php
<?php

namespace MyCorp\FormsBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder('mycorp_forms');

        $treeBuilder->getRootNode()
            ->children()
                ->booleanNode('favorite_submenu_enabled')->defaultFalse()->end()
            ->end()
        ;

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

#### Extension

*mycorpforms/src/DependencyInjection/MyCorpFormsExtension.php*

```php
<?php
namespace MyCorp\FormsBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Knp\Bundle\SnappyBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Processor;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\Extension;

class MyCorpFormsExtension extends Extension
{

    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $containerBuilder)
    {
        $loader = new YamlFileLoader(
            $containerBuilder,
            new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../../config/packages')
        );
        $loader->load('mycorp_forms.yaml');

        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $processor = new Processor();
        $config = $processor->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $containerBuilder->setParameter('mycorp_forms.favorite_submenu_enabled', $config['favorite_submenu_enabled']);
    }
}
```

#### Yaml

Additionally I added the desired `mycorp_forms.yaml` inside the bundles `./config/packages/` dir.

**This is the actual file required in the projects:**

*mycorpforms/config/packages/mycorp_forms.yaml*

```
mycorp_forms:
    # Enable Favorite-Sub-Menu (Requires Knp-Snappy-Bundle !)
    favorite_submenu_enabled: false
```

---

The bundle installs flawlessly in any of my projects, however no `mycorp_forms.yaml` file is created. Obviously this requires `symfony/flex` which is so far required by the bundle itself.

---

**Q: What do I miss here?**
**Q: How can this `yaml`-file automatically be added when the bundle is installed?**
I read the documentation up and down numerous times, but to be honest, I get more confused every time.

---

Thank you very much for any help or explanation!

Comment: the yaml config file is not created by anything in your code. It is created by a *recipe*. In order for the additional file(s) to be created, you will need to get your project added to the [recipe repository](https://github.com/symfony/recipes-contrib)

Comment: Oh, now that makes much more sense. I see, this can be done with private bundles too: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/flex_private_recipes.html. Thanks for pointing me there!

Comment: Or just copy/paste the files yourself which is what our ancestors had to do.  It is confusing that config/bundles.php will get updated without further effort but there is no builtin way to copy a file.

Comment: Just to be clear: But the code given above is needed to retrieve the config values from that self-created config-file to use its values in the bundle code, right?

Comment: Well no.  The $loader->load is for services files, not configuration.  So make those lines go away.  The framework will automatically load all the files in config/packages regardless of their names.  Anything under the `mycorp_forms:` section then gets passed to `MyBundle::load` in the $configs variable.  The processor basically merges the $configs data with your Configuration object.  So yep, very confusing to get something to work.  Might help to look at some of the existing Symfony bundles.

Comment: Here is a very simple working example using the [AbstractBundle](https://github.com/cerad/s6bundle/blob/main/src-my-bundle/src/CeradMyBundle.php) class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires **Symfony Flex**

To have a `.yaml` config file being generated/updated automatically, there is 2 possible ways:

- **public** bundle: register it in the public [recipe repository](https://github.com/symfony/recipes-contrib)
- **private** bundle: set up your own private [flex recipe repository](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/flex_private_recipes.html)